# Running xelatex programmatically from R script

Tags: r, latex, xelatex

I have a `.tex` file that I need to compile to PDF using XeLaTeX (I am using fontspec, among other packages). Using RStudio, I can successfully generate a PDF via the Compile PDF command, having specified XeLaTeX as the engine in my RStudio preferences.

How can I programmatically invoke this compilation from a script? I've investigated `tools::texi2pdf()`, but when running it on my file I get an error saying `The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX`, and I don't see a way of specifying that I want to use XeLaTeX instead of plain LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for now is to do a call to `system()`. For instance:

```
system("xelatex --shell-escape my-script.tex")
```

If there are better solutions that don't require a `system()` call (I've heard of issues with cross-platform compatibility), that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the environment variable `PDFLATEX=xelatex` and `tools::texi2pdf` will respect it.

From `texi2dvi --help`:

> The values of these environment variables are used to run the
> corresponding commands, if they are set:
>
> BIBER BIBTEX DVIPDF DVIPS EGREP HEVEA LATEX MAKEINDEX MAKEINFO PDFLATEX PDFTEX SED T4HT TEX TEX4HT TEXINDEX TEXINDY THUMBPDF_CMD

From [tools::texi2dvi](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/texi2dvi.html) docs:

> All the approaches should respect the values of environment variables LATEX, PDFLATEX, MAKEINDEX and BIBTEX for the full paths to the corresponding commands.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with the following solution:

```
install.packages("tinytex")   
require("tinytex")}
install_tinytex(force = TRUE)
tlmgr_install('montserrat') 
xelatex('Report.tex')
```

This code install [TinyTex](http://yihui.name/tinytex/), then it installs the font package *montserrat* with *tlmgr_install* function.